# SharePoint online - mass edit of script editor snippet in subsites

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, script-editor-webpart

*Note* - wasn't sure how to display a tag with brackets as plain text.

So, I have a Site with a bunch of subsites. Within the subsites There is a page with a script editor, and within the script editor is an empty 'a' tag:

```
<a href=""> click </a>
```

I want to fill those with links of the current subsite with to a specifically named permissions group.

example:

```
<a href="https://websitename.sharepoint.com/sites/mainsite/subsite1/subsite2/subsite3/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=###">click</a>
```

My question:

Is there some way that will allow me to edit these in mass? instead of one at a time?

Comment: Are you using classic experience in SharePoint online? Is `/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=###` this part common in URL for all after subsite URL (including `MembershipGroupId`)?

Comment: It is a direct link to a permissions group so a user can go there to add people as needed with the correct permissions based on their link, used ### as a placeholder for the group id number.  

as for am I using classic? I have no idea for certain, (I took over this from a previous employee), but its format on this specific page looks like classic, but most of the site is modern best i can tell

Comment: I think you will have to manually edit the web part on each site to make these changes.

Comment: I was afraid of that, all my research I did came to that conclusion lol, figured I would as the community for good measure.